# Git library for Ruby or Python?

Tags: python, ruby, git

I'm looking for a Ruby or Python implementation of the Git client that can be used to update and commit changes in a local repository.

I prefer if the library does not use shell commands at all but keeps everything in "pure code".

Are there any?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's also [Dulwich](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dulwich), a Python implementation of the Git file formats and protocols.

Answer (score 6):

[Grit](http://github.com/mojombo/grit) gives you object oriented read/write access to Git repositories via Ruby.

```
require 'grit'
include Grit
repo = Repo.new("/Users/tom/dev/grit")

repo.commits
# => [#<Grit::Commit "e80bbd2ce67651aa18e57fb0b43618ad4baf7750">,
      #<Grit::Commit "91169e1f5fa4de2eaea3f176461f5dc784796769">,
      #<Grit::Commit "038af8c329ef7c1bae4568b98bd5c58510465493">,
      #<Grit::Commit "40d3057d09a7a4d61059bca9dca5ae698de58cbe">,
      #<Grit::Commit "4ea50f4754937bf19461af58ce3b3d24c77311d9">]

...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check out [ruby-git gem](http://github.com/schacon/ruby-git).

Comment: Which is currently (October 2015) the most used wrapper for Git in Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

For Python, there is the [Dulwich](http://Samba.Org/%7Ejelmer/dulwich/) library which @RyanWilcox already mentioned.

For Ruby, there unfortunately is no Git library. There is [Grit](https://GitHub.Com/Mojombo/Grit/), which implements a subset of Git in Ruby and wraps the command line tools for some additional features, but only supports the subset of Git that GitHub needs. And you could use either [JGit](http://Eclipse.Org/jgit/) or [Git#](http://WWW.Eqqon.Com/index/GitSharp) via JRuby or IronRuby.

Answer (score 3):

There is now [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/): a C library [sponsored by Github](https://github.com/blog/752-libgit2-a-git-linkable-library) with [many bindings](http://libgit2.github.com/#bindings) including Ruby and Python.

Answer (score 0):

[GitPython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython/) has an object-oriented API similar to Grit:

```
>>> #$ pip install GitPython
>>> import git
>>> repo = git.Repo('.')
>>> repo.git_dir
'/home/hobs/src/twip/.git'
>>> repo.bare
False
>>> repo.untracked_files
[u'twip/scripts.bak/__init__.py',
 u'twip/scripts.bak/cat_tweets.py',
 u'twip/scripts.bak/clean.py',
 u'twip/scripts.bak/explore.py',
 u'twip/scripts.bak/generate.py',
 u'twip/scripts.bak/plot_globe.py',
 u'twip/scripts.bak/skeleton.py']
>>> repo.head.ref
<git.Head "refs/heads/master">
>>> repo.tags
[<git.TagReference "refs/tags/0.0.1">,
 <git.TagReference "refs/tags/0.0.2">,
 <git.TagReference "refs/tags/0.0.3">]
```

Comment: The main problem about GitPython is that it's a wrappper on top of the actual git executable, with all that it entails. Dulwich and libgit2 work at pure-python or C-library level.

Comment: @GicomoLacava yes, a pure python implementation like Dulwich has a lot of dependency and cross-platform advantages. But a wrapper for an executable has the advantage that you can be sure that it correctly implements a particular version of the executable's file formats etc, with all the latest features of that executable. It's more DRY and more future proof. That said I'll definitely try `dulwich` the next time I need git within a pure python module, so I don't pollute my module with dependency complications.